# SVG path follow flipped & rotated + not following path

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, anime.js

I'm trying to use AnimeJS to make a div follow a path.

There are two problems:

1. The object does not follow exactly on the path of the svg
2. The path it is following looks to be rotated and flipped

I worked out the fix for issue #2 was to add css to the SVG: `transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(180deg);` but it has caused problems further down the line.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8wvort9k/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="cont">

  <div class="will_follow"></div>

  <svg...></svg>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cont {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.cont svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.will_follow {
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: 3px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

JS

```
var path = anime.path('#tracking path');

anime({
  targets: '.will_follow',
  translateX: path('x'),
  translateY: path('y'),
  rotate: path('angle'),
  easing: 'linear',
  duration: 10000,
  loop: true
});
```

[jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/8wvort9k/1/)

---

I imagine it's something to do with my svg export itself? Is it the viewport in the svg?

Thanks for taking the time to consider my question

Comment: First, simplify your svg, there are a lot of unnecessary groups. Second, give a specific ID to the path you're trying to follow. Third, figure a way to make it responsive. In this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oauegLkt/) (which is different from codepen by the way) you'll see that the path is followed correctly just not responsive (since the translate values applied are not percentages but pixels).

Comment: I'm sorry but the things you are pointing out are not problems and you produced a fiddle of what I had already posted I cannot use? 1. Why should the SVG contents matter if my selector is exact? (`#tracking path`) There is only 1 path element in `#tracking`. 2. I specifically said I cannot use `transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(180deg);` so that is not an answer to the problem which is exactly what you only changed in the jsfiddle. There is clearly a problem with the `AnimeJS` library here and not my code

Comment: I posted the problem in their [issues section](https://github.com/juliangarnier/anime/issues/530)

Comment: 1 - When I edited your jsfiddle initially, the path was not even being followed, maybe you weren't done working on it. 2 - The svg content does not matter indeed, it's simply about simplifying your file structure and minimizing your code. Secondly, this is a problem with your SVG not `AnimeJS`, on your SVG is applied `transform : scale(1 -1);` which is messing up the CSS transforms used by `AnimeJS`. I opened your SVG in Illustrator and fixed it. Here is my updated and working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/85ngkdot/2/). Edit : didn't see Arrangemonk answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:

sorry, this is just a partial answer:
your svc is transformed with scale(1,-1) (that flips it upside down) and then the css scales the svg to 100% screensize, but the followed path still has the same size.

After The Transformation:

https://jsfiddle.net/eqkwj8zg/

html

```
<div class="cont">


<div class="will_follow"></div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1440" height="810" viewBox="0 0 1440 810" style="stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-width:0.5">
<g font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="16" style="fill:none;stroke:black">
<g style="fill:#5ccf43;stroke-width:7">
<path d="M0 810L0 0C0 0 0 0 0 0L1440 0C1440 0 1440 0 1440 0L1440 810C1440 810 1440 810 1440 810L0 810C0 810 0 810 0 810Z"/>
</g>
<g stroke-width="0.5">
<g fill="#fdf4ad">
<path d="M0 810L0 597.6 0 597.6 0 700.9C3.1 701.1 191.4 692.6 184.4 597.3 184.4 582.2 196.7 569.9 211.9 569.9L295.3 569.9 295.3 413.5 209.8 413.5C194.6 413.5 182.3 401.2 182.3 386.1L182.3 209.9C182.3 194.8 194.6 182.5 209.8 182.5L1151.9 182.5C1167.1 182.5 1179.3 194.8 1179.3 209.9L1179.3 377.4C1179.3 392.6 1167.1 404.9 1151.9 404.9L1040.5 404.9 1039.8 491.4C1039.7 506.4 1027.4 518.6 1012.4 518.6L793.4 518.6C778.3 518.6 766.1 506.4 766 491.4L765.2 359.3 545.7 359.3 545.7 627.6 930.6 627.6C945.7 627.6 958 639.9 958 655L958 700.5 1440 700.5 1440 755.3 930.6 755.3C915.4 755.3 903.1 743.1 903.1 727.9L903.1 682.4 518.3 682.4C503.2 682.4 490.9 670.1 490.9 655L490.9 331.8C490.9 316.7 503.2 304.4 518.3 304.4L792.5 304.4C807.6 304.4 819.8 316.6 819.9 331.7L820.7 463.8 985.1 463.8 985.8 377.3C985.9 362.2 998.2 350 1013.3 350L1124.5 350 1124.5 237.3 237.2 237.3 237.2 358.7 322.8 358.7C337.9 358.7 350.2 371 350.2 386.1L350.2 597.3C350.2 612.4 337.9 624.7 322.8 624.7L239.3 624.7C237 656.8 232.7 693.2 239.3 722.8 249.4 772 57.3 781 58.3 810L0 810Z"/>
</g>
</g>
<path id="followme" d="M0 785.3C75.3 700 167.9 747.1 204 645L216.4 597.3 322.1 597.3 322.1 386.1 209.1 386.1 209.1 209.9 1151.3 209.9 1151.3 377.4 1012.6 377.4 1011.7 491.2 792.7 491.2 791.9 333.2 520.3 333.2 520.3 655 929.9 655 929.9 727.9 1440 727.9" style="fill:none;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:0.8;stroke:#f00"/>
</g>
</svg>
</div>
```

javascript

```
var path = anime.path('#followme');

anime({
  targets: '.will_follow',
  translateX: path('x'),
  translateY: path('y'),
  rotate: path('angle'),
  easing: 'linear',
  duration: 10000,
  loop: true
});
```

css

```
.cont {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.will_follow {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Here i fed the svg throu a svg optimizer which applied tansformations,(this removed the flipping of the image)
and then removed the scaling.
now the red dot follows the path correctly,i didnt find out how to scale the animation to screen size thou

in conclusion: you need to find the transformation applied to the svg (svg transformations and dom transformations) and apply them to your animation